# SQLite query in android to search all fields for a match to an input

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to search an entire SQLite table for a `like` match to string input from the user??

something like:

```
cursor = db.query("myDBName", null, "* like '%"+input_string+"%'", null, null, null, null);
```

I just want to say "look through every field in the database for anything matching input_string"

Thanks all! Sorry if this is a poorly formatted question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that SQLite doesn't support such syntax. 
If you already know your table's structure, you can search each column one by one, or build a long "col1 LIKE .. OR col2 LIKE.." query.